# I get error LNK2019 when I try to compile zeromq sources

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, zeromq, libsodium

I'm trying to compile the zeromq sources and I have the following error:

I'm using Visual studio 2013 update 4 / windows 7 x64

First of all I compile the libsodium library satisfactorily.

Then I link the libsodium header files directory path to additional dependencies  and libsodium.lib to additional library directories. I also specify the name of library in additional dependencies.

I try to compile it under win32 architecture and x64 architecture but I get the same errors.

I know that a __imp prefix is used as a bridge to the function that I want to use so if I linked the libraries appropiately why do I get this error?

Console log:

```
1>Creating library E:\zmq\libzmq\builds\msvc\vs2013\libzmq\..\..\..\..\bin\Win32\Debug\v120\dynamic\libzmq.lib and object E:\zmq\libzmq\builds\msvc\vs2013\libzmq\..\..\..\..\bin\Win32\Debug\v120\dynamic\libzmq.exp
1>ctx.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__randombytes_close referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::ctx_t::~ctx_t(void)" (??1ctx_t@zmq@@QAE@XZ)
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__sodium_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::curve_client_t(struct zmq::options_t const &)" (??0curve_client_t@zmq@@QAE@ABUoptions_t@1@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sodium_init
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_keypair referenced in function "public: __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::curve_client_t(struct zmq::options_t const &)" (??0curve_client_t@zmq@@QAE@ABUoptions_t@1@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_keypair
1>zmq_utils.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_keypair
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_beforenm referenced in function "private: int __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::process_welcome(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?process_welcome@curve_client_t@zmq@@AAEHPBEI@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_beforenm
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box referenced in function "private: int __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::produce_hello(class zmq::msg_t *)" (?produce_hello@curve_client_t@zmq@@AAEHPAVmsg_t@2@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_open referenced in function "private: int __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::process_welcome(unsigned char const *,unsigned int)" (?process_welcome@curve_client_t@zmq@@AAEHPBEI@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_open
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_afternm referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::encode(class zmq::msg_t *)" (?encode@curve_client_t@zmq@@UAEHPAVmsg_t@2@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_afternm
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_open_afternm referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::decode(class zmq::msg_t *)" (?decode@curve_client_t@zmq@@UAEHPAVmsg_t@2@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_box_open_afternm
1>curve_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__randombytes referenced in function "private: int __thiscall zmq::curve_client_t::produce_initiate(class zmq::msg_t *)" (?produce_initiate@curve_client_t@zmq@@AAEHPAVmsg_t@2@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__randombytes
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_secretbox referenced in function "private: int __thiscall zmq::curve_server_t::produce_welcome(class zmq::msg_t *)" (?produce_welcome@curve_server_t@zmq@@AAEHPAVmsg_t@2@@Z)
1>curve_server.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__crypto_secretbox_open referenced in function "private: int __thiscall zmq::curve_server_t::process_initiate(class zmq::msg_t *)" (?process_initiate@curve_server_t@zmq@@AAEHPAVmsg_t@2@@Z)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably compiling libsodium in a static way.

Try to compile it dinamically and link it again.

Answer (score 1):

Such errors are also able to occur when you have a wrong set calling convention at your project.